# How to get rid of top float in header on github hosted site.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, github

I've built a bootstrap static page and uploaded it github. In my browser it looks perfectly fine, but when hosted on github, there seems to be white padding at the top above the logo and header.

http://sparkgeo.github.io/maptiks-landing/integrations.html

Any ideas on how to get rid of this?

Comment: Make sure to validate the page, as your HTML is a bit broken. `<head` content is spilling into the `<body>` area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS file add this rule:

```
   [name="google_conversion_frame"] {
    display:none
    }
```

I think that this kind of sintax isn't perfectly implemented on older browser, so just to be surer you can use instead:

```
iFrame {
  display:none
  }
```

Comment: this .iFrame isn't working. Hmm. any other thoughts?

Comment: just iFrame NOT .iFrame

Answer (score 0):

Its the

```
<iframe name="google_conversion_frame"
```

either hide - display:none

or

set position - position:absolute

Comment: maybe its the github code. Try to set position of the iframe to absolute on window load